# How to correctly vectorize Pandas column from lookup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I am not a Python whiz so forgive me if this is a stupid question.

I have imported a csv which has been imported into pandas, called `pw` and looks like this:

```
                 datetime  outlet  inlet  flow
0     2023-04-12 00:00:00    38.5   48.5   3.3
1     2023-04-11 23:55:00    38.5   48.0   3.0
2     2023-04-11 23:50:00    38.5   48.5   3.6
3     2023-04-11 23:45:00    38.5   48.0   3.3
4     2023-04-11 23:40:00    38.5   48.0   3.3
...                   ...     ...    ...   ...
```

I have made some conditional probability lookup tables:

```
pgf = pw.groupby('flow')['outlet'].value_counts()/pw.groupby('flow')['outlet'].count()
fgp = pw.groupby('outlet')['flow'].value_counts()/pw.groupby('outlet')['flow'].count()
```

which can be accessed like this:

```
pgf[some flow value][some pressure value]
fgp[some pressure value][some flow value]
```

i want to create a `pgf` and `fgp` column in `pw`. i thought i should be able to write:

```
pw['p_p'] = pgf[pw['flow']][pw['outlet']]
```

which i thought would take the flow and outlet value from each row to calculate the probability value and place it in the 'p_p' column, however when i run this i get the following message:

KeyError: '[38.5 38.5 38.5 ... 47.5 47.5 47.5] not in index'

but I do not understand how this can be so when the `pgf` was created using the data of `pw`

pgf is `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

---

i am able to get around this issue using:

```
for i in range(len(pw)):
  flow = pw['flow'].loc[i]
  pres = pw['outlet'].loc[i]
```

however i feel that this must be the slowest way to achieve this

Comment: the accepted answer if worse than your original approach, using `apply` on `axis=1` is most often the slowest. I added another approach using `merge`, which is the vectorial way of aligning data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're facing is related to the way indexing works with multi-index Pandas series. Using the for loop as you've done is definitely not the most efficient way, especially when working with large datasets. Instead, you can use the `.apply()` method with a lambda function to access the multi-indexed series.

```
pw['p_p'] = pw.apply(lambda row: pgf.get((row['flow'], row['outlet']), 0), axis=1)
pw['f_p'] = pw.apply(lambda row: fgp.get((row['outlet'], row['flow']), 0), axis=1)
```

I used the `apply` method on the dataframe `pw` along `axis=1` (which means you are applying the function row-wise). For each row, I used a lambda function to look up the values in the `pgf` or `fgp` series.
Then I used the `get` method of the series to handle the possibility of a key not being present (this will return `0` in that case, but you can modify it as you see fit).

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code using directly [`value_counts(normalize=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), and by using a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
d = {'p_p': ['flow', 'outlet'],
     'f_p': ['outlet', 'flow']}

for k, (a,b) in d.items():
    pw[k] = pw[[a, b]].merge(pw.groupby(a)[b].value_counts(normalize=True)
                               .reset_index(name=k))[k]
```

Output:

```
              datetime  outlet  inlet  flow  p_p  f_p
0  2023-04-12 00:00:00    38.5   48.5   3.3  1.0  0.6
1  2023-04-11 23:55:00    38.5   48.0   3.0  1.0  0.6
2  2023-04-11 23:50:00    38.5   48.5   3.6  1.0  0.6
3  2023-04-11 23:45:00    38.5   48.0   3.3  1.0  0.2
4  2023-04-11 23:40:00    38.5   48.0   3.3  1.0  0.2
```